# Wordpress htaccess redirect to https

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a problem with redirect loops on my wordpress site.

I want to:

1. Redirect www and http requests to https
2. A request which is to the page rvplayer should remain http or be redirected to http

I am currently experiencing redirect loops when requests are made to http://www or https://www or www.

The code I have in .htaccess is currently

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/rvplayer/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Go to http if on /rvplayer/

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=80
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /rvplayer/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Why would one page not get HTTPS?

Comment: Are you using cloudflare on your domain?

Comment: WordPress itself will be configured for one or the other and is likely redirecting you back again - resulting in a redirect loop.

Comment: One page doesn't get HTTPS because it is HTTP audio.  Yes we are using a CDN but not Cloudflare